# How to prevent second click on radio button if it was already checked in Android?

Tags: java, android, radio-button, onclicklistener

I want to increase the score by 1, when someone clicks on the right radio button. If someone clicks 2 times, the score is increased by 2. I am trying to prevent that with a boolean but it doesn't work. Were am i wrong?
This is my code:

```
                boolean isChecked;

                answer[j].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        RadioButton checkedRadioButton = ((RadioButton) v);
                        if (isChecked) {
                            if (checkedRadioButton.isChecked() & CorrectAnswer == 1) {
                                score++;
                                isChecked = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Thanks!

Comment: I defined ` boolean isChecked;` in the `OnClickListener` but when i click the radio button, the scrore  remains zero. What can i do?

Comment: Your code won't actually compile, unless you've not been precise about where `isChecked` is declared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you don't need the value outside the `OnClickListener`, the easiest thing to do is to make it a member variable of that class:

```
new View.OnClickListener() {
  private boolean isChecked = true; // HERE

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    RadioButton checkedRadioButton = ((RadioButton) v);
    if (isChecked) {
      if (checkedRadioButton.isChecked() && CorrectAnswer == 1) {
        score++;
        isChecked = false;
      }
    }
  }
};
```

You also need to set its value to `true` initially, since it will otherwise be `false` and so the conditional's body never runs.

Comment: Accepted. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

You could also simply use

```
if (!checkedRadioButton.isChecked())
```

instead of a dedicated checker

```
 if (isChecked)
```